# R won't interpret function with parameter value, uses parameter name

Tags: r

I'm trying to write a small package that will connect R to spack builds of R packages with R and Linux dependencies so users don't have to hunt these down. The sole function is as follows:

```
install.packages <- function(package_name) {
  print(package_name)
  source(file.path("/software/spack/opt/lmod/init/R"))
  module(use, "/software/modules/linux-ubuntu22.04-x86_64/Core")
  module(load, package_name)
  .libPaths(c(unlist(strsplit(Sys.getenv("R_LIBS"), ":"))))
}
```

Usage and lmod error look like this:

```
> easyR::install.packages("r-tidyverse/2.0.0_r/4.3.0")
[1] "r-tidyverse/2.0.0_r/4.3.0"
Lmod has detected the following error:  The following module(s) are unknown: "package_name"

Please check the spelling or version number. Also try "module spider ..."
It is also possible your cache file is out-of-date; it may help to try:
  $ module --ignore_cache load "package_name"

Also make sure that all modulefiles written in TCL start with the string #%Module
```

The parameter value is read in correctly as evidenced by the print statement, but the value doesn't get passed into the "module(load..." statement, which just uses the parameter name. How can I pass the value into this statement?

I've tried various versions of eval() and deparse() to try to have the value interpreted, which either result in the same error, or sometimes what seem to be a shell syntax (sh: ) error about an unexpected "("

Comment: (1) Is your package named `easyR`? Is that different from [`easyr`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/easyr/index.html)? If so, then ... it can be more confusing to use a package that differs by case alone than perhaps the "ease" of allowing a user to install a package. (2) What is `module`? (3) Perhaps this will be answered by #2, but you use `use` and `load` as if they are defined somewhere, but your function does not define them. What are they? (4) Rewriting `.libPaths()` and dropping existing paths seems a recipe for confusion and pain, not sure what you are gaining.

Comment: Seems `module` only take symbols and not variables. Perhaps there is a parameter that tells the function as to whether the argument should be taken as a symbol or as a variable. eg the function `library` has the parameter `character.only` that enables you to pass a variable into the function `library(variable, character.only = TRUE)`. Try and see whether that is that is the case. Otherwise, you will be forced to use NSE to pass a variable into the function

Comment: @r2evans Yes, sorry for the confusion: was hoping to just do some quick prototyping so hadn't really cleaned up the nomenclature. easyR is my package, but should probably change the name. I believe module, use, and load are lmod functions brought in by the source line: this was written by a collaborator. They are loading modules from the lmod utility.

Comment: What is the `lmod` utility?

Comment: @r2evans this is in an hpc environment. lmod is a lua-based utility for handling environment and path variables for different packages users may need in shared environments.

Comment: Okay, but regardless ... `module(load, ...)` is completely opaque to us yet is at the core of your question. I can't help you with an error inside a function we know nothing about.